# Why did Andor mention his gloves here?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

A stormtrooper meets Andor and Tivik in the streets:

> STORMTROOPER 1: What's all this? Come on, let's see some scandocs.
>
> Andor: Yeah, of course. Just... **My gloves**.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [official novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_(novelization)) suggests that he's indicating that his scandocs are in his gloves, which he keeps in a leg pocket.

> Cassian kept his eyes off Tivik. There was nothing he could do to coax
> the man into playing along, to urge him to make no move. He kept
> smiling his small, reassuring smile at the stormtroopers, even as his
> blood pumped fiercely with the promise of a weapon, a planet killer.
> **“Yeah, of course,” he said. “My gloves?”**
>
> **He indicated a pocket with a gesture. The stormtroopers didn’t object.
> Thieves were common on Kafrene, and they’d doubtless seen stranger
> hiding spots.**

But you're not wrong. It's a weird line.

Comment: I always thought it was that Cassian's gloves made fumbling with a fastening more difficult, and used that as an excuse to keep the troopers off guard while he positioned himself to get to his blaster to get those shots off before they could react.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins - Unfortunately, because the film was such a glorious mess, they haven't released any of the versions of the screenplay. All we have to go on is the novelisation. The scene is even different in the junior novel.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins - Note that he's not wearing gloves in this scene that he would need to remove, but that could easily be because of the way that it's edited.

Comment: It is an absolute glorious mess. I do think it is poetically fitting that Rogue One was saved in the edit.